# How to enable private-mode on kiln?

Tags: kiln, private-mode

according to 
https://tezos.gitlab.io/user/various.html

private mode can be enabled with the arguments

```
tezos-node run --rpc-addr [::] --private-mode \
                               --no-bootstrap-peers \
                               --bootstrap-threshold=1 \
                               --connections 1 \
                               --peer <public-node-ip>
```

How to enable this in kiln?

Kiln has the file etc\kiln\args to pass command line arguments

setting 
`KILNARGS="--kiln-node-custom-args --private-mode"`

is valid syntax, but how to add the additional parameters?

eg, the following does **NOT** work:
`KILNARGS="--kiln-node-custom-args --private-mode --no-bootstrap-peers"`

Comment: Just from a shell escaping perspective I would expect that you'd need to put quotes around the arguments you want to provide, something more like:

`KILNARGS="--kiln-node-custom-args '--private-mode --no-bootstrap-peers'"`